# Custom Dropdownlist cannot be Validated

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, validation, html.dropdownlistfor

I use a custom Dropdownlist in my MVC project and I can validate all the elements except from this ddl without any problem. When I change its type from "MyDropdownListFor" to "DropDownListFor", the problem goes away (the boorder of the related ddl turns to red). I think the type of this custom ddl is different or I had to add some extra parameters to this ddl in my custom helper. What may the problem?

*Updated Code*

**Custom Helper:**

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyDropdownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<MySelectItem> list, string optionLabel, object htmlAttributes)
{
    return MyDropdownList(htmlHelper, ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression), list, optionLabel, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
}

public static MvcHtmlString MyDropdownList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, IEnumerable<MySelectItem> list, string optionLabel, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    TagBuilder dropdown = new TagBuilder("select");
    dropdown.Attributes.Add("name", name);
    dropdown.Attributes.Add("id", name);

    StringBuilder options = new StringBuilder();

    // Make optionLabel the first item that gets rendered.
    if (optionLabel != null)
        options = options.Append("<option value='" + String.Empty + "'>" + optionLabel + "</option>");

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        if(item.Disabled == "disabled")
            options = options.Append("<option value='" + item.Value + "' class='" + item.Class + "' disabled='" + item.Disabled + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>");
        else
            options = options.Append("<option value='" + item.Value + "' class='" + item.Class + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>");
    }
    dropdown.InnerHtml = options.ToString();
    dropdown.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(dropdown.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

**View:**

```
//This DDL can be validated without any problem
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.HasDoneAnyProject, ViewData["HasDoneAnyProject"] as SelectList,"---- Select ----", new { name = "hasDoneAnyProject", id = "hasDoneAnyProject"})


//This Custom DDL cannot be validated
@Html.MyDropdownListFor(m => m.MeetingId, ViewBag.MeetingData as List<MyHelpers.MySelectItem>, 
"---- Select ----", new { name = "meetingId", id = "meetingId"})
```

**Css:**

```
.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    background-color: #fee;
}

.input-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

.field-validation-error {
    color: #f00;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    display: block; /**/
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #f00;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}
```

*Added Code*

**Html (Generated):** When the validation message appears the lst situation for the related DDL are as below:

```
 <!-- This is from working DDL -->
 <select name="HasDoneAnyProject" id="hasDoneAnyProject" data-val-required="Mandatory 
 field" data-val-number="The field HasDone Any Project? must be a number."    
 data-val="true"
 class="ErrorField"><option value="">---- Select ----</option>
 <option value="51">Yes</option>
 <option value="52">No</option>
 </select>
 <span class="ValidationErrors">Mandatory field</span>

 <!--This is from non-working (custom) DDL -->
 <select name="MeetingId" id="MeetingId"><option value="">---- Select ----</option>
 <option class="" value="1">Paris</option>
 <option class="disabled" value="2">Leeds</option>
 <option class="" value="4">Amsterdam</option>
 <option class="disabled" value="6">Edinburg</option>
 <option class="disabled" value="79">London</option></select>
 <span class="field-validation-valid ValidationErrors" data-valmsg-replace="true"     
 data-valmsg-for="MeetingId"></span>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the custom output html and css looks like?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I added the generated html. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Hmm, well the "answer" is that your `select` element needs to have the same `data-val-required="[your message]"` as the working one.  That's what tells the validator that it is required.  Beyond that though, I don't know enough MVC to tell you how to get it to specify that for you...